# alternating inputs in two threads

Tags: python, multithreading

```
import threading
import time
def Tommy():
    i=0
    while True:
        lock.acquire()
        combine = input('Tommy:')
        lock.release()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        i=i+1
        if combine == 'q':
            break
def Cherry():
    i=0
    while True:
        lock.acquire()
        combine = input('Cherry:')
        lock.release()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        i=i+1
        if combine == 'q':
            break
lock = threading.Lock()
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=Tommy)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=Cherry)
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```

May I know why this code is so smart that it can alternately call Tommy and Cherry, so that they never talk to themselves? I think it is because of acquiring lock, but I have no idea why it can do so.

Comment: Please ensure the code is correctly formatted, as it will not run as is.

Comment: thanks reminding me about that, just updated it.

Comment: It's not "alternately calling" them, it's just that you have them in sync with a wait time of 0.5 seconds each. Try changing the wait times to something larger and out of sync to give more time than the input takes eg. 20 seconds and 30 seconds, and you'll see they're not always alternating.

Comment: I just tried turning it to 30 seconds, but still it is alternating, first Tommy, then Cherry, then Tommy, then Cherry...

Comment: is it that time.sleep(n) serves as a gap for the other thread to enter, so that the other thread can acquire the lock and get input?

Comment: @desmondng any feedback please?

Comment: i did not reply that quick because the result of your code is not my expectation, so I am going through the documentations actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Python documentation:

> When more than one thread is blocked in acquire() waiting for the
> state to turn to unlocked, only one thread proceeds when a release()
> call resets the state to unlocked; which one of the waiting threads
> proceeds is not defined, and may vary across implementations.

It means that any other thread can't enter the `lock` block of code, it any other thread have already entered the block and have not released `lock` yet.

`lock` does not prevent other code blocks (not locked) to process in other threads.

```py
import threading
import time


def notifier():
    # Not blocked by the lock
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Notify")


def tommy(lock: threading.Lock):
    i = 0
    while True:
        # prevent other threads from performing operations when lock is blocked by another thread
        with lock:
            combine = input('Tommy:')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        i += 1
        if combine == 'q':
            break


def cherry(lock: threading.Lock):
    i = 0
    # prevent other threads from performing operations when lock is blocked by another thread
    while True:
        with lock:
            combine = input('Cherry:')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        i += 1
        if combine == 'q':
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _lock = threading.Lock()
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=tommy, args=(_lock, ))
    thread2 = threading.Thread(target=cherry, args=(_lock, ))
    notify_th = threading.Thread(target=notifier, daemon=True)
    notify_th.start()
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
```